# How to get Monitor Handle from Index or Name?

Tags: windows, winapi, autoit, multiple-monitors

A C++ version ([How can I get an HMONITOR handle from a display device name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987695/how-can-i-get-an-hmonitor-handle-from-a-display-device-name)) has no solution provided (at least in my circumstances that require non-OOP code such as in AutoIt).

I'm adapting an AutoIt script that uses WinAPI functions to support multi-monitor Windows 7+ systems. I can provide either monitor/device Name or it's Index, but some functions require an HMONITOR handle instead.

I *cannot* get the HMONITOR by Window or by pixel or point, which would be quite easy. No, I need to get the handle from name or index only, and I need a non-OOP solution (ideally AutoIt & WinAPI calls but non-OOP pseudo-code would be fine).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get an HMONITOR handle from a display device name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987695/how-can-i-get-an-hmonitor-handle-from-a-display-device-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the handle of a (real) monitor by its index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412926/get-the-handle-of-a-real-monitor-by-its-index)

Answer (score 0):

The function below returns an array of the following structure:

```
| hMonitor   | xPosMonitor | yPosMonitor | widthMonitor | heightMonitor |
| 0x00010001 | 0           | 0           | 1366         | 768           |
| 0x0001024  | 1366        | -236        | 1920         | 1080          |
```

**Code:**

```
#include-once
#include <Array.au3>
#include <WinAPIGdi.au3>

Func _getMonitorInfos()
    Local $aPosition, $aMonitorData = _WinAPI_EnumDisplayMonitors()

    If IsArray($aMonitorData) Then
        ReDim $aMonitorData[$aMonitorData[0][0] + 1][5]
        For $i = 1 To $aMonitorData[0][0] Step 1
            $aPosition = _WinAPI_GetPosFromRect($aMonitorData[$i][1])
            For $j = 0 To 3 Step 1
                $aMonitorData[$i][$j + 1] = $aPosition[$j]
            Next
        Next

        Return $aMonitorData
    EndIf
EndFunc

Global $aMonitorData = _getMonitorInfos()

_ArrayDisplay($aMonitorData)
```

*hMonitor value* is contained by the array `$aMonitorData[1][1]`.